# interpreting output for glmmTMB for zero-inflated count data

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, glmmtmb

I have been trying to read all the documentation I have, but I'm still not sure what the difference is between the "conditional" and zero-inflated models in the output of the glmmTMB. Below is some code modelling a zero-inflated count dependent variable (alcoholic drinks, standardized). The observations are nested within persons (153 persons, 90 observations each).

I am wondering if the "Conditional model" is simply the original model that doesn't consider zero-inflation, whereas the "zero-inflated" is the model with this factored in (hence I would report these stats only?). In addition, I am wondering whether the zero-inflated model includes 0 values or not, given that the estimates change in direction (and sometimes in significance). Or maybe I have this all  the other way around. Any clarifications would be helpful.

Also when playing around with the output, the `allEffects` function only plots the conditional model. I am wondering if there's an easy way to plot the zero-inflated model as well.

Thanks in advance!

```
> model1 <- glmmTMB(drinks_round ~ sex + cann_used + cann_g + other_type + n_used + day + wDay 
                                   + (1|studyID), 
                   zi = ~sex + can_used + cann_g + other_type + n_used + day + wDay,
                   family=nbinom2, data=can1
                   )

> summary(model1)
 Family: nbinom2  ( log )

Formula:
   drinks_round ~ sex + cann_used + cann_g + other_type + n_used + day + wDay 
                  + (1 | studyID)
Zero inflation:
   ~sex + cann_used + cann_g + other_type + n_used + day + wDay
Data: can1

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 24795.8  24931.4 -12379.9  24759.8    13752 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 studyID (Intercept) 0.4657   0.6825  
Number of obs: 13770, groups:  studyID, 153

Overdispersion parameter for nbinom2 family (): 4.97 

Conditional model:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      1.1459925  0.2080129   5.509 3.60e-08 ***
sex             -0.1729803  0.1209996  -1.430   0.1528    
cann_used        0.0640049  0.0416621   1.536   0.1245    
cann_g           0.1866736  0.0311277   5.997 2.01e-09 ***
other_type      -0.0330603  0.0691555  -0.478   0.6326    
n_used           0.3266708  0.0660834   4.943 7.68e-07 ***
day              0.0010574  0.0005845   1.809   0.0705 .  
wDayweekday     -0.2464173  0.0314343  -7.839 4.54e-15 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Zero-inflation model:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      0.8868254  0.1014340   8.743  < 2e-16 ***
sex              0.0638217  0.0495552   1.288   0.1978    
cann_used       -0.2525820  0.0593977  -4.252 2.12e-05 ***
cann_g           0.2174713  0.0410397   5.299 1.16e-07 ***
other_type      -0.1837736  0.0996293  -1.845   0.0651 .  
n_used          -0.3920739  0.0720337  -5.443 5.24e-08 ***
day              0.0002897  0.0008903   0.325   0.7449    
wDayweekday      0.3367418  0.0487646   6.905 5.00e-12 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Okay so I made some progress on understanding the model. 

You need both the conditional and zero-inflated outputs because... 
- the conditional output represents the zero portion (or a logistic regression)
- the zero inflated output represents a "mixture" model of the two distributions - one for the subgroup who reports zero or close to zero and one for the subgroup who doesn't report zero. 

However, my collaborator was wondering whether the zero-inflated portion of the model predicts likelihood of a zero value or likelihood of a 1 value? Or is it truly in between 0 to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The zero-inflation model estimates the probability of an extra zero such that a positive contrast indicates a higher chance of absence [...]; this is the opposite of the conditional model where a positive contrast indicates a higher abundance"

So, answering your comment, it is indeed the likelihood of zero (the alternative being "not 0" rather than 1). By the way the ziformula also allows you to add random effects, just like in your conditional formula.

Pages 382-383 explain all components of the model summary:

Brooks, M. E., Kristensen, K., van Benthem, K. J., Magnusson, A., Berg, C. W., Nielsen, A., Skaug, H. J., Machler, M., & Bolker, B. M. (2017). glmmTMB balances speed and flexibility among packages for Zero-inflated Generalized Linear Mixed Modeling. The R Journal, 9(2), 378-400. https://doi.org/10.32614/RJ-2017-066

Comment: Thanks, that is a helpful reframe of what is happening, I had trouble interpreting that part of the document. And I've updated my model to include the random effects as well. 

So, if the zero-inflation is predicting likelihood of 0 vs. not-zero, is the conditional model just predicting 0 vs. 1 like a true logistic regression?

Comment: Okay it looks like the conditional model is predicting 0 or the "absence" of the variable you are looking at.

Comment: The ziformula is a binomial model turned up side down, it tells you which of your predictors increase the probability of no drinks vs some drinks. The conditional model tells you which predictors influence the number of drinks, for those cases where some drinks have been had. (I am now really curious about your predictors)